# How to find out which values a function f is called when using scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, global-variables, numerical-integration

I have a function `f(x) = 1/x^2` and I evaluate the integral from 0 to 1 using `scipy.integrate.quad`. The `scipy.integrate.quad` is an adaptive integration routine, and I would like to know in which regions of [0,1] is the function f evaluated. So, for which values of x is the function f called when making an estimate of the integral?

I'm thinking of using a global variable and appending the x values called to it to keep track of the which x values get used. However, I'm not too familiar on how to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

The plan is to then plot a histogram to see what regions in the interval [0,1] are evaluated the most.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a decorator class that saves each value `x`  before evaluating the function:

```py
class MemoizePoints:
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.points = []

    def __call__(self, x, *args):
        self.points.append(x)
        return self.fun(x, *args)

@MemoizePoints
def fun(x):
    return 1 / x**2

quad(fun, a = 1e-6, b = 1.0)
```

Then, `fun.points` contains all the `x` values for which the function `f` was evaluated.

Here, the decorator `@MemoizePoints` is just syntactic sugar for

```py
def fun(x):
    return 1 / x**2

fun = MemoizePoints(fun)
```